# Standard URL jQuery validations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate a url with jQuery. Is there a simple way to do this?

Is there any regular expression which validates the correct format? I tried with some regular expression which failed to validate properly. Can you suggest better way to do it?

I need a standard regular expression which validates as exact as possible.

Comment: The jquery validate plugin has a url rule built in: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation // http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method

Comment: @rory-mccrossan - Its a better answer. thank you. Kindly post this as answer if u wish

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You can do that but if you only need to validate an URL I think loading a complete plugin is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin has a URL rule built in:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below logic..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function isUrl(s) {

var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
alert(regexp.test(s)); }   </script>
```

and call like this

```
 <body onload="isUrl('http://www.google.com');">
```